# Blog on subdirectory

Tags: blog, performance, subdirectory, directory-listing

I have a very simple doubt relate to blogs on subdirectories. I have a main website built with WordPress and I want a blog with it.

When we read about the recommendation to put a blog on the subdirectory, like www.mydomain.com/blog, does it means I have to make a new WordPress install on a subdirectory or I just have to create a page called Blog and use it from the same WordPress installation of the main Website?

What concerns me is that my main website uses a very resource-intensive plugin (wpgeodirectory) and I'm afraid that a blog on the same install may affect the performance of its service.

I'm worried about SEO gain versus performance. The blog will have simple texts and images, nothing very different than the usual and it will be used to attract site traffic to the main website. Should I be worried about sharing the same WP install between the main website and his blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is just a misunderstanding of what is intended.  Your blog doesn't have to be in a subdirectory, it can just be a link within wordpress.  In fact WOrdPress is set up to do exactly what you want.

*Dashboard > Settings > Reading* you will see you can select the home page and the posts page.

[image]

It is that simple

Comment: I have no idea how it will affect SEO.  It is a dark art I don't pretend to understand.  My guess though is that the page will look pretty much the same to a search engine as the URL will be the same.  What makes you think having a page in WordPress will have any affect on performance compared to having a completely different wordpress install?  To me it seems like you are just creating more work for yourself with 2 dashboards to manage.

Comment: You are right. But what makes me think my performance will be affected is that I will have more plugins on the same install. But I decided to go as you suggested to try it out. I will not accept your answer for now, just to stimulate someone else with another perspective on the subject. But thanks!!

Comment: I disagree.  By having a second install you would need to duplicate plugins.  Besides, if you are having a straightforward blog, why do you need any additional plugins.  If you are interested, here is my opinion on plugins and why they should be kept to a minimum - https://setup.123host.com.au/plugins.php

Comment: I have the same opinion and practice on plugins. I keep to the very minimum. But today I talked with the developer of the plugin WPGeodirectory and he advised me better about the question. I also thought ou the question with the help of this article: https://wpbloggingnerd.org/seos-verdict-blog-in-a-subdomain-subdirectory-and-on-the-site/

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to my question on this post, that seems to be very helpful.

https://wpbloggingnerd.org/seos-verdict-blog-in-a-subdomain-subdirectory-and-on-the-site/

But maybe you also should read the comments that Steve did just above.

Thank you all!